# Replace image inside a link with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Considering the following code:

```
<a href="tutu">
    <img src="ver.gif" class="logo" id="header-logo" title="Coco">
</a>
```

and script:

```
$('a[href$="tutu"]').each(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).prop('title'));
})
```

I'm trying to replace the image with the title text, so it displays coco instead of the image.

Could you help me ?

Comment: are you trying to update the `src` attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake here is that `this` here is
`<a href="tutu"><img src="ver.gif" class="logo" id="header-logo" title="Coco"></a>`

and it does not have a property title, its child has, therefore you have to do something like:

```
$('a[href$="tutu"]').each(function () {
   $(this).text($(this).children().prop('title'));
});
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

```js
$('a[href$="tutu"]').each(function() {
  $(this).find('img').replaceWith($(this).find('img').prop('title'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="tutu">
  <img src="ver.gif" class="logo" id="header-logo" title="Coco">
</a>
<a href="tutu">
  <img src="ver.gif" class="logo" id="header-logo" title="Loco">
</a>
<a href="tutu">
  <img src="ver.gif" class="logo" id="header-logo" title="Zoco">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below code

JS:

```
$('a[href$="tutu"]').each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).prop('title'));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `img` element is a child of the `a` tag so you have to find your required img first under the a tag then get the image title attribute and set the content of `a` tag to this value:

```js
$('a[href="tutu"]').each(function () {
    var title=$(this).find('img').attr('title');
    $(this).html(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="tutu">
    <img src="ver.gif" class="logo" id="header-logo" title="Coco">
</a>
```